# Creating New folder on some host by directory.createDirectory

Tags: c#, directory

I want to create new folder with the  current Year name in host (asp.net 4.5 and C#), but if I write

```
  Directory.CreateDirectory("~/poroje/"+s);
```

the access deny error happen. and if I use

```
  Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s));
```

there is no error but directory didn't create!
anyone Can help me please?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't create the second time, or are you looking at the wrong directory?

Comment: It should create. Since Server.MapPath is the way for it. What happens when you execute the statement? Are you sure nothing happens?

Comment: What does `Server.MapPath("~/poroje/"+s)` evaluate to at runtime?

Comment: Do a Console.WriteLine(Server.MapPath("~/poroje/" + s)) and see where the actual path is of where you are creating the folder.  My guess is that it's being created, but not where you think it should be.

Comment: In some cases in worked, but not always and I cant understand why!

Comment: try using `Server.MapPath(@"~/poroje/"+s);`

Comment: Ok I will test it now

Comment: So Thanks @Jegadeesh and All other! after adding @ the problem solved!

Comment: try `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("the path you want");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `Server.MapPath(@"~/poroje/"+s);`

Comment: if you use this, you don't need to check for the folder exist.